# Send multiple of items to WCF Dataservice at once?

Tags: c#, web-services, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm using WCF Data Service as a way to allow other webservice in the project to connect to the database. My problem is that I our project has a crawler that add tens of items to the database every hour.

Using **AddToItems** method (which is auto generated by ADO.NET) leads to **timeout exception** or at least it makes the crawler in need to wait for a lot of time taking into consideration that Addto method handles each independently.

*Notes :
1-  I've added an interceptor on adding to items to perform some actions when a new item is added.

2- WCF Data services Service Operations doesn't allow taking parameters of a user defined data type , that prevented me from creating a service operation that takes a list of items as a parameter to be able to handle multiple items at each time and at the same way to allow the client to handle it asynchronously.

When I tried to serialize this list so it can be treated as a string , an exception has occurred because of the length limit of the url even when POST is used instead of Get.

Update : Saveing Changes via BeginSaveChanged and EndSaveChanged solved the problem to some extent but I'm still looking for a better solution

Comment: You should extend the timeout

Comment: I want to increase the performance not to increase the timeout :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the OData feature Batch can address your requirement:

```
    var client = new Container(serviceUrl);
    client.Format.UseJson();

    DefaultBatchCustomer customer0ToAdd = new DefaultBatchCustomer { Id = 10, Name = "Customer 10" };
    DefaultBatchCustomer customer0ToAdd = new DefaultBatchCustomer { Id = 11, Name = "Customer 11" };

    client.AddToDefaultBatchCustomer(customer0ToAdd);
    client.AddToDefaultBatchCustomer(customer1ToAdd);

    var response = await client.SaveChangesAsync(SaveChangesOptions.BatchWithSingleChangeset);
```

and the request looks like:

```
POST http://jinfutanwebapi1:9123/DefaultBatch/$batch HTTP/1.1
OData-Version: 4.0;NetFx
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0;NetFx
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_8ce61768-e8bb-4117-954b-9bc43e05baef
Accept: multipart/mixed
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
Host: jinfutanwebapi1:9123
Content-Length: 1772
Expect: 100-continue

--batch_8ce61768-e8bb-4117-954b-9bc43e05baef
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_b36bec94-fc3b-4d89-99cc-0610fcec8148

--changeset_b36bec94-fc3b-4d89-99cc-0610fcec8148
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST http://jinfutanwebapi1:9123/DefaultBatch/DefaultBatchCustomer HTTP/1.1
Content-ID: 13
OData-Version: 4.0;NetFx
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0;NetFx
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services

{"@odata.type":"#WebStack.QA.Test.OData.Batch.Tests.DataServicesClient.DefaultBatchCustomer","Id":10,"Name":"Customer 10"}
--changeset_b36bec94-fc3b-4d89-99cc-0610fcec8148
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST http://jinfutanwebapi1:9123/DefaultBatch/DefaultBatchCustomer HTTP/1.1
Content-ID: 14
OData-Version: 4.0;NetFx
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0;NetFx
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services

{"@odata.type":"#WebStack.QA.Test.OData.Batch.Tests.DataServicesClient.DefaultBatchCustomer","Id":11,"Name":"Customer 11"}
--changeset_b36bec94-fc3b-4d89-99cc-0610fcec8148--
--batch_8ce61768-e8bb-4117-954b-9bc43e05baef--
```

Comment: I had mentioned this solution in my question as an update :) I was asking if there is another options